# Custom script works flawlessy when using terminal, but custom service doesn't work on startup, but if i systemctl start it it executes fine

Tags: bash, scripts, xubuntu, systemd, services

I have a custom service in /etc/systemd/system/microphone_disable_startup.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable microphone on startup
After=alsa-restore.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/bin/check_mic_startup
```

The script that is executed is check_mic_startup located in /opt/bin

```
#!/bin/bash

# DEBUG: touch /home/GeorgeMP/Desktop/testfile_works

i_toggle=$(amixer get Capture toggle | grep -c "\[on\]")
if [ $i_toggle = 2 ] ; then
        amixer -q set Capture toggle
fi
amixer -q set Capture 0%
echo Microphone turned OFF
exit 0
```

As you can see I have tried debugging the service with the touch command, and it works flawlessly, even when used by the service. The problem is with the more complex commands in the script.

Doing a systemctl status on my custom service, i can check that the service succeded without errors.

```
microphone_disable_startup.service - Disable microphone on startup
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/microphone_disable_startup.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2020-12-01 17:36:39 CET; 8min ago
    Process: 610 ExecStart=/opt/bin/check_mic_startup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 610 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 01 17:36:39 GeorgeMP systemd[1]: Started Disable microphone on startup.
Dec 01 17:36:39 GeorgeMP systemd[1]: microphone_disable_startup.service: Succeeded.
```

However, after restarting/shutting down even though it executed successfully, the command didn't execute or it happened without any effect because

```
amixer get Capture
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 63
  Front Left: Capture 63 [100%] [30.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 63 [100%] [30.00dB] [on]
They are 100% and turned [on].
```

They should be 0% and [off]

If i execute /opt/bin/check_mic_startup from the terminal, it works flawlessly. Even so if i do systemctl start microphone_disable_startup.service. It just doesn't work when used by my custom service microphone_disable_startup.service
What's the issue?

EDIT 1:

I change my script to this to contain the /opt/bin directory too

```
#!/bin/bash

# DEBUG: touch /home/GeorgeMP/Desktop/testfile_works

# USE THESE IF NEEDED SOMEWHERE ELSE
    #DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
    #DISPLAY=":0.0"
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/bin"
i_toggle=$(/usr/bin/amixer get Capture toggle | grep -c "\[on\]")
if [ $i_toggle = 2 ] ; then
    /usr/bin/amixer -q set Capture toggle
fi
/usr/bin/amixer -q set Capture 0%
echo Microphone turned OFF
env > /home/GeorgeMP/Desktop/environment
exit 0
```

And i check and every command can be accessed by the script in the new environment.

By the way, the environment file that was created on my Desktop is

```
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
PWD=/
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
INVOCATION_ID=549485b12a4149bb889e55d42711e923
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
JOURNAL_STREAM=9:26568
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/opt/bin
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
_=/usr/bin/env
```

So it contains the /opt/bin path. It still doesn't work... but when i run the script in the terminal it works...

Comment: Could be due to the environment variables (or lack of). For example, in your shell run an `env` and in your startup script put `env > /home/GeorgeMP/Desktop/environment` and see the difference. First thing I would try is put full paths to things in your script so not `amixer` but `/usr/bin/amixer` or wherever it is.

Comment: @codlord can you please check my edit, i did as you told me but it still doesn't work... I have no idea what to do

Comment: PATH read from left to right most logic would be to place the custom path first (even if it does not have anything to do with the problem).

Comment: @bac0n Thanks for telling me I didn't know that! I changed it immediately! But unfortunately, the problem is still the same...

Comment: think you are missing `[Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target` section in your service, don't forget to enable your service

Comment: This is not a `systemd` issue. Your script runs an audio application which relies on `pulseaudio` which in turn is a user service and cannot be accessed until after you login with your user and even then `pulseaudio` is not accessible by your `systemd` custom service. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1266207)